# multipart/form with backbone and spring boot

Tags: ajax, spring, backbone.js, multipartform-data, ajaxform

```
addVendorLicense:function(){
                    var self=this;
                    if(app.vendorId){

                     $('#licenseForm').ajaxSubmit({
                        url: "vendorLicense/create/"+app.vendorId,
                        async:false,
                        success: function (res) {
                            alert(res.message);
                           self.addLicenseRow();
                        },
                        error:function(res){
                            alert(res.message);
                        }
                    });
                    }
                    else{
                        alert("Please Add a vendor First");
                    }   
                    return false;
             },**

***Spring Controller***

@RequestMapping(value = "/create/{vendorId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<VendorLicenseResponse> createLicense(LicenseRequest licenserequest,@PathVariable("vendorId") String vendorId) {}

***Request Object***

public class LicenseRequest extends BaseRepresentation {

@JsonIgnore

    private String licenseType;

    private String licenseName;

private String licenseNumber;

    @JsonIgnore
    private String expirationDate;

    @JsonIgnore
    private List<String> statesCovered;

    private String terms;

    private String brokerNumber;

    private String organizationId;

    @JsonIgnore
    private CommonsMultipartFile insuranceFiles;

}
```

I am trying to map a multipart form data to LicenseRequest object.When the form is submitted with File then the rquest is parsed properly but when form is submitted without file then server gives 400 bad request error.Can some one tell me How to make the file optional in multipart/form-data.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting it in  the request object you can grab it directly and make it optional, I'm not sure if you can specify the optional part in a custom object.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create/{vendorId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<VendorLicenseResponse> createLicense(LicenseRequest licenserequest,@PathVariable("vendorId") String vendorId,
@RequestParam(value = "insuranceFiles", required = false) CommonsMultipartFile insuranceFiles) {
   if(insuranceFiles != null){}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.The problem is that I am using jquery form plugin to submit the form.So when No file is selected the plugin sends empty string in file object .Which spring tries to map to the commonsmultipartFile oject.Can you suggest How to prevent form plugin to stop sending empty string when no file is selected.